# Eclipse Mars, open type reference

Tags: eclipse

I have project A and project B in Eclipse Mars.
Project A is packaged and used as dependency in project B's classpath (Eclipse's build path).
I mostly work from project A, the annoying thing is that when i want to open a type within project A with the Ctrl+Shift+T combination, it opens the compiled type in A's dependency of project B. 
This page does not show anything about [this](http://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-dialog-open-type.htm).

any advice?

Comment: Are you looking for: ``Project properties -> Java Build Path -> Projects tab -> Add``?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than include ProjectA's package (JAR?) on ProjectB's build path, you should instead make ProjectB depend on ProjectA.

Open ProjectB's properties and then add the dependency here:

[image]

Don't forget to remove the ProjectA JAR from ProjectB's build path (in the **Libraries** tab above).